# how to find a string which is exist or not in some specific datacolumns of the datatable using LINQ query in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable, datacolumn

I'm trying to find a string which is exist in some specified column of datatable or not. for example the DataTable contains 5 DataColumns. I want to find the string which is exist in any of the DataColumn1 or DataColumn2. 
I tried the below code part to get the single column1 values.

```
IEnumerable<string> query = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        select dr.Field<string>("ID");
```

How can I get the values of 2 or more columns?

Comment: Can you give an example of several rows and what are you trying to get from the rows?

Comment: select new object[] {dr.Field<string>("ID"), dr.Field<string>("ID1")};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return anonymouse type:

```
 var query = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
    select new {ID = dr.Field<string>("ID"), Column2 = dr.Field<string>("Column2")};
```

And than you can use fields of that type:

```
var Column2 = query.First().Column2;
var ID = query.First().ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
IEnumerable<string> query = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                    where dr.Field<string>("ID").Contains("stringValue") || dr.Field<string>("DataColumn1").Contains("stringValue")
                                    select new { Id = dr.Field<string>("ID"), DataColmn1 = dr.Field<string>("DataColumn1") };
```

Comment: It is possible answer . the answer return to only string List how to return more then one column

Comment: Updated the answer. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

try code:

```
 IEnumerable<string> query = (from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select dr.Field<string>("ID")+ dr.Field<string>("ID")).ToList();
```

Another Solution :

IEnumerable support to One Generic Type Arguement can't support Multi Return type

Create A New Class

```
    class customer
      {
        Public string Id {get;set;}
        Public String Name {get;set;}
      }
```

and used to linq

```
 IEnumerable<customer> query = (from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new customer{ id= dr.Field<string>("ID"),name= dr.Field<string>("name")}).ToList();
```